# How to get ios simulator logs during ios automation in selenium using appium in java

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

I am unbale to get the logs for ios simulator.

I tried with finding the folder core simulator but unable to do

Comment: Kindly some one help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can start the appium with option :

```
appium --show-ios-log
```

Hope that one helps. Thank you